# How to make multiple API requests with while loop in Python?

Tags: python

I need to make a request to an API that only responses with maximum of 200 results. If the total amount of data is more than 200, the API responses also with a parameter `lastKey` that I need to pass to a new request. When all the data has been returned the `lastKey` -param is not returned anymore.

My question is how to do it in a simple, clean way? This is how I make the first request and I can see if there is the `lastKey` -param or not:

```
url = 'https://example.com'
moreData = False

with requests.Session() as api:
     data = requests.get(url)
     try:
       data.raise_for_status()
     except HTTPError as e:
       return Response(status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
result = data.json()

if 'lastKey' in result:
    url = 'https://example.com&lastKey=' + result['lastKey']
    moreData = True
```

How could I do this whole thing for example inside a while -loop?

Comment: `while not 'lastKey' in result:`?

Comment: You can use `lastKey` as a parameter by using `request.get(url, params={"lastKey": "value"})` and you aren´t using your `api`-object at your with-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the first result out of the `while` loop, then call your api *while* you have "lastkey" in the result

```
url = 'https://example.com'

with requests.Session() as api:
    data = requests.get(url)
    try:
        data.raise_for_status()
    except HTTPError as e:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
result = data.json()

while 'lastKey' in result:
    url = 'https://example.com&lastKey=' + result['lastKey']

    with requests.Session() as api:
        data = requests.get(url)
        try:
            data.raise_for_status()
        except HTTPError as e:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    result = data.json()
```

Comment: `api` is never used. What's the point of the `with` blocks?